# Possible questions about the Tate-Shafarevich subgroup of a Galois hypercohomology group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology, abelian-groups

$\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}$
Let $n=1,2$. There are infinite torsion *abelian* groups  $H^1$, $H^2$  killed by some natural number $m$.
There are finite subgroups
$$ {\rm Sha}^1  \subset  H^1,\quad         {\rm Sha}^2  \subset  H^2$$
These groups  $H^n$ and ${\rm Sha}^n$ for $n=1,2$ are invariants of a connected reductive group $G$ over a number field $F$.

We (Tasho Kaletha and I) can explicitly compute these abelian groups and subgroups
(sorry for self-promotion).

> **Question.**  What are reasonable questions about a pair $({\rm Sha}^n, H^n)$ for $n=1,2$ ?

Examples of answered questions:

> **Q1.** Can  ${\rm Sha}^n$ be  nonzero?

**A1.** Yes (Borel-Serre 1964 for $n=1$, Sansuc 1981 for $n=2$).

> **Q2.** Write a formula for ${\rm Sha}^n$.

**A2.** Answered: Kottwitz 1984 for n=1, Borovoi-Kaletha 2023 for n=2.

> **Q3.** Is ${\rm Sha}^n$, when nonzero,  a direct factor of  $H^n$ for $n=1,2$?

**A3** for $n=2$: never! (because there is a divisible subgroup $D \subseteq H^2$ containing ${\rm Sha}^2$).

**A3** for $n=1$: There is an example when ${\rm Sha}^1$ is not a direct factor of  $H^1$ (a GAP calculation).

> **Question.** What are  other reasonable questions, maybe more sophisticated versions of Question 3?

Here I explain what these groups $H^n$ and ${\rm Sha}^n$ are.
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a number field $F$.
We consider the homomorphism
$$\rho\colon\ \wt G\twoheadrightarrow [G,G]\hookrightarrow G,$$
where $\wt G$ is the universal cover of the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$.
Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus, and set $\wt T=\rho^{-1}(T)\subset \wt G$,
which is a maximal torus in the simply connected semisimple $F$-group $\wt G$.
We consider the Galois hypercohomology groups
$$H^n=H^n_{\rm ab}(F,G):={\Bbb H}^n(F,\wt T\to T)$$
with $T$ in dimension $0$ and $\wt T$ in dimension $-1$. These Galois hypercohomology groups do not depend on the choice of $T$.
We set
$$ {\rm Sha}^n= {\rm Sha}^n_{\rm ab}(F,G):=\ker\bigg( H^n_{\rm ab}(F,G)\to\prod_{v\in {\mathcal V}(F)} H^n_{\rm ab}(F_v,G)\bigg)$$
where ${\mathcal V}(F)$ is the set of all places of $F$, and $F_v$ denotes the completion of $F$ at $v$. Then the finite abelian group ${\rm Sha}^1_{\rm ab}(F,G)$ is in a canonical bijection with the usual Tate-Shafarevich kernel
$${\rm Sha}^1(F,G)=\ker\bigg( H^1(F,G)\to\prod_{v\in {\mathcal V}(F)} H^1(F_v,G)\bigg).$$